# Do Russian parents call their children by full name to scold them?

Tags: этикет

In English-speaking countries, when a child is being bad, parents often address her in full name to discipline. Do Russian parents do the same thing? I’m curious to know.

Comment: Yes, sure, quite often, but not necessarily. Russian can make dozens of diminutives (hypocorisms) or augmentatives with different emotional coloring of practically any name, some of them in a particular family for a particular child may sound much more threatening than the full name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they do.

This as far as I can judge is a feature of any language which has names with hypocorisms (pet names).

Let me quote Anna Wierzbicka's "Semantics, Culture, and Cognition". Sorry about quoting the Russian translation as I don't have the English original handy:

> Ван Бурен (Van Buren 1977: 114) подчеркивает, что по отношению к детям полные имена звучат неодобрительно и что "чем детей сильнее ругают, тем более полные формы имен при этом используют". (Например: *Jessie, no* "Джесси, нет"; *Jessica, don't do that!* "Джессика, не смей этого делать!".) Кроме того, что таким свойством обладают только маркированные полные имена, у которых есть немаркированные краткие формы (т. е. *James* или *Jessica*, но не *Martin* или *Clare*), надо отметить также, что "неодобрительная" коннотация никак не может являться частью инвариантного значения таких форм. Отец может похвалить сына, сказав: *Well done, James!* "Молодец, Джеймс!", но может также и одернуть: *Stop it at once, James!* "Прекрати сейчас же, Джеймс!". То общее, что есть в обоих употреблениях, как раз и содержится в компоненте "Я хочу говорить с тобой так, как (обычно) не говорят с детьми".

Russian full name contains a patronymic (father's name with a special suffix). Also, Russian has the [T–V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) (addressing a person formally with the plural "you").

Using the full name with the patronymic and the plural "you" to address a child is the absolute level of putting them into this "adult mode":

> Мария Ивановна! Перестаньте ковырять в носу и послушайте мать. // Maria Ivanovna! Stop picking your nose and listen to your mother.

Comment: I've seen it a couple of times in my life. They have never done this to me.

Comment: Bonus: now I know how to say "pick your nose" in Russian :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sometimes people in Russia do it exactly this way. Also I witnessed when people were calling their dog by it's full name when they were mad at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "full name" something like "John Dow, you're bad", instead of "John, you're bad", Russian parents don't use it (at least, I never heard it around). As @Quassnoi said, we can use something like "Jessy" VS "Jessica" when we want to notice children actions (it can be either good or bad reasons). Patronymic... I use them only for little children, as a sign of my affection.

Answer (score -4):

nope...

My actual name is Vladislav, but they call me Vlad, Vladuha, Vladon, Vladik, Vla, and just Sinyok (son)

Comment: Ask them what name would be used in "XXXX вы своим футболом помяли новую семёрочку БМВ у соседа. С завтрашнего дня ...." sentence. I'm quite sure none of the once you've mentioned would be used.